# Params do not work after refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

**Edit: I can't get the params.id because nuxt-link pass it to detail page.**

I'm trying to build a blog with NuxtJS.

This is the link for blog detail page.

```
<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'category-slug', params: { slug: slug, id: id, category: category } }">
```

It works well but after I refresh detail page (i.e: tech/hello-world), it returns **Cannot read property 'author' of null**

_slug.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>slug {{ $route.params.id }}</h1>
  {{ loadedPost.author }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vuex from "vuex"
import axios from "axios"

export default {
    asyncData(context) {
      console.log(context.params.id)
      return axios.get('https://howto-a9089.firebaseio.com/posts/' + context.params.id + '.json')
        .then(res => {
          return {
            loadedPost: res.data
          }
        })

    },
  }
</script>
```

I think there's a problem with asyncdata. Why it happens?

Comment: Have you inspected res.data?

Comment: @RicoChen Yes i did. res.data gives me correct response but as i mentioned above It works when i click to nuxt-link but after refresh the page, i'm getting error.

Comment: Have you set a default value for `loadedPost` in `data()` as per [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/)?

Comment: @Flaex I think the cause is similar to this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/945 and one of the possible solutions is https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers. Here's the solution. _slug.vue only gets params.id when user clicks the below button.

```
<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'category-slug', params: { slug: slug, id: id, category: category } }">
```

When user enters directly this url or refresh the page, there will be no params.id. So I needed to GET data by "slug".

Thanks to Firebase:

```
return axios.get('https://howto-a9089.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy="slug"&equalTo=' + '"' + params.slug + '"' + '&print=pretty')
```

Result: I got SEO friendly url now. :) (i.e url.com/tech/hello-world)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/), you should set a default value for `loadedPost` so you don't get errors like this while the asynchronous data is loading

```
export default {
  data() {
    return { loadedPost: {} }
  },
  asyncData({ params }) {
    return axios.get(`https://howto-a9089.firebaseio.com/posts/${params.id}.json`)
        .then(res => ({
          loadedPost: res.data
        }))
  }
}
```

Without this, `loadedPost` is null when your template attempts to display `loadedPost.author` and that's why you get that error.